# Computing constrained tuple efficiently

Tags: list-manipulation

I was wondering what would be the fastest/most efficient way to compute the elements of the set

$$\left\{ x\in\mathbb{Z}^{d} \middle| \sum^{d}_{i=1}|x_i| \leq n  \right\}$$.

I think I could use Reduce, e.g.,

```
Reduce[Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString@i], {i, d}] \[Element] Integers &&
   Total[Abs[Table[Symbol["x" <> ToString@i], {i, d}]]] <= n]
```

for some given $d$ and $n$, but I am also guessing that there are more efficient ways to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can generate the partitions of $n$ into $d$ nonnegative integers with

```
p[n_, d_] := Join @@ Permutations /@ (IntegerPartitions[n + d, {d}] - 1)
```

so that, for example,

```
p[3, 2]
(*    {{3, 0}, {0, 3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}}    *)
```

Adding all possible signs of the numbers and eliminating duplicates,

```
t[n_, d_] := Union @@ Outer[Times, p[n, d], Tuples[{-1, 1}, d], 1]

t[3, 2]
(*    {{-3, 0}, {-2, -1}, {-2, 1}, {-1, -2}, {-1, 2}, {0, -3},
       {0, 3}, {1, -2}, {1, 2}, {2, -1}, {2, 1}, {3, 0}}          *)
```

### update: a bit faster, and more complete

Less duplicate removal by more explicit construction:

```
p[n_, dd_] :=
  Join @@ Outer[Times, IntegerPartitions[n, {dd}, Range[n]], 
                       Tuples[{-1, 1}, dd], 1]
t[0, d_] := {ConstantArray[0, d]}
t[n_, d_] := Join @@ Table[DeleteDuplicates[
  Join @@ (Permutations[PadRight[#, d]] & /@ p[n, dd])], {dd, d}]
g[n_, d_] := Join @@ Table[t[m, d], {m, 0, n}]

g[9, 9] // Length // AbsoluteTiming
(*    {1.47089, 1462563}    *)
```

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate it. I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this. Feels like doing loops would be faster than getting all signs and removing duplicates. What do you think?

Comment: There are not that many duplicates. Duplicates only come from having zeros in the list (because $+0 = -0$). I doubt you'll be faster with loops, though. Let's see; maybe someone can come up with a faster method!

Comment: Doesn't this method only yield solutions that are _strictly equal_ to $n$ instead of less than or equal to?

Comment: Actually you are right, I checked and this generates those integers vectors whose one norm is strictly equal to $n$. I guess one needs to 'loop' now over from 0 to $n-1$ to add the remaining vectors.

Comment: @NonDairyNeutrino yes you're right! Sorry I missed this somehow. As @NoobNoob says, loop over `m`, see update!

Comment: @Roman I will accept the answer, I have been trying other solutions and I think this one is already pretty fast. I was wondering if you could explain me (or direct me to an explanation) of the first step in your first solution? Why is it that permutations + partitions gives you all lists of nonnegative numbers whose sum is equal to n?

Comment: `IntegerPartitions[n + d, {d}]` gives all ordered ways of expressing the number $n+d$ as a sum of $d$ positive integers. If we subtract 1 from each one of these integers, then `(IntegerPartitions[n + d, {d}] - 1)` gives all ordered ways of expressing the number $n$ as a sum of $d$ non-negative integers. For example, `With[{n = 3, d = 2}, (IntegerPartitions[n + d, {d}] - 1)]` gives `{{3, 0}, {2, 1}}`. By computing all possible permutations of these partitions and joining them into a single list, `p[3, 2]` gives `{{3, 0}, {0, 3}, {2, 1}, {1, 2}}`.

Answer (score 1):

The set is effectively (in addition to @Roman's realization of the integer partitions) looking for all the $d$ dimensional vectors (over $\mathbb{Z}$) that are within (under the 1-norm) the closed ball of radius $n$.  With that in mind, we can tell *Mathematica* to solve for just that.

Given specific dimension and bounding norm, we can use

```
f[n_, d_] := SolveValues[Norm[x, 1] <= n && x \[Element] Vectors[d, Integers], x]
f[2, 2]
```

> {{-2, 0}, {-1, -1}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 1}, {0, -2}, {0, -1}, {0, 0}, {0,
> 1}, {0, 2}, {1, -1}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 0}}

Note here the crux of the code is the specification of the 1-norm with the second argument of [`Norm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Norm.html) and the [`Vectors`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Vectors.html) domain with specific dimension and field over which the vectors are.

Comment: Much nicer but MUCH slower than the enumeration I used in my solution.

Comment: I agree, I appreciate this view quite a bit.